# Encryption Cesar hard to make loop

Tags: matlab, encryption, while-loop

I have a program to do for school where a decryption should be made. It's really simple encryption-style where should only move the letters some steps. For example if you have 3 steps, then the 'A' becomes 'D' and 'G' becomes 'J'. They way I solve this problem is by looking ah the fact that the English languages most common letter is 'E'. So I check for common letters in the text and assume that they represent 'E'. If it is not the most frequent letter then it should be the second most frequent or third etc..It also uses uppercase letters for easier identification with ASCII system. Problem is that in my first text, the roll is not 5 or 10 (which i found with the second most frequent letters) but something else, and I cannot find how to make a nice loop of it, so now it looks real ugly.
Thanks for the help

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

%Opens txt file
fid=fopen('krypteradett.txt','rt');
text = fscanf(fid,'%c',Inf)

%Makes it uppercase
txtversal = upper(text);

%checks unique letters and removes unneeded spaces
bokst = unique(txtversal);
bokst = strtrim(bokst);

c = histc(txtversal, bokst);
cdescend = sort(cd,'descend');


%Prints out each unique letter and how many times they are repeated
fprintf('"%c" is %n times\n', [bokst; c])

%Finds the most frequent letter
storsta = max(max(cd));
ix=find(c==max(c));
frekvbokst = bokst(ix);
fprintf('The most frequent letter is "%cd" and can be found %d times.\n', [frekvbokst; storsta])

%Since 'E' is the most common letter in the English language, it calculates
%how many "rolls" have been made to come to the new letter. If 'G' is the
%most frequent letter in our text, then it matches how far it is from the
%letter 'E' in capital ASCII.
s = double(frekvbokst);
eiascii = double('E');
rullning = (s - eiascii);
fprintf('the roll is %d step.\n', rullning)

textascii = double(txtversal);

%Capital English letter in ASCII only range from 65 to 90, if it is out of
%range it should jump the whole alphabet (26 letters) forward/backward. And
%if it is 0, then it should become 26 to keep the spaces. Still needs
%rework as it works very bad
T = (textascii >= 65) & (textascii <= 90);
bratek(T) = (textascii(T) - rullning);
bratek(bratek < 64) = bratek(bratek < 64)+26;
bratek(bratek == 64) = bratek(bratek == 64)+26;
bratek(bratek > 90) = bratek(bratek >90)-26;
bratek(bratek == 26) = bratek(bratek == 26)-26;

char(bratek)

%Asks if the text made sense
ratt = input('Is the text reasonable? (1) for yes and (2) for no.  ');

%If the text didn't make any sense, the program does the same thing as
%before just with the second most frequent letter and matches it to the
%letter 'E' to see how many rolls have been made.
if ratt == 2
    nyttstorsta = max(c(c~=max(c)));
    ip=find(c==nyttstorsta);
    nyttfrekvbokst = bokst(ip);
    nyttfrekvbokst = nyttfrekvbokst(1);
    fprintf('The second most frequent letter is "%c" and can be found %d times.\n', [nyttfrekvbokst; nyttstorsta])

    s = double(nyttfrekvbokst);
    eiascii = double('E');
    rullning = (s - eiascii);
    fprintf('The roll is %d step.\n', rullning)

    textascii = double(txtversal);

    T = (textascii >= 65) & (textascii <= 90);
    nyttbratek(T) = (textascii(T) - rullning);
    nyttbratek(nyttbratek < 64) = nyttbratek(nyttbratek < 64)+26;
    nyttbratek(nyttbratek == 64) = nyttbratek(nyttbratek == 64)+26;
    nyttbratek(nyttbratek > 90) = nyttbratek(nyttbratek >90)-26;
    nyttbratek(nyttbratek == 26) = nyttbratek(nyttbratek == 26)-26;


    char(nyttbratek)

    ratt = input('Is the text reasonable? (1) for yes and (2) for no.  ');

elseif ratt == 1
    disp('You have now decrypted the text: ')
    char(bratek)
end

%Prints out diagram with most frequent letters (still needs rework as it
%doesn't print out on diagram which are the most frequent ones). It keeps
%it to the 10 most frequent ones at least.
pie(cfix)
```

Comment: Maybe use some subroutines instead of putting it all in one method? If you just aggregate everything as one large block of code it will always look messy. PS it's "Caesar".

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. If you have a better question, you should ask a new one and add a link to this one for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Fellesh - your method to decrypt the cipher text seems overly complicated especially given that the Cesar Cipher is used to encrypt the (secret) message.  Since the encryption simply shifts the letters x characters to the "right" (i.e. A to D) then why not take a brute force approach and check all possible shifts?  Since only upper case letters are used, and there are just 26 letters in the alphabet, then that would imply that there are only 26 possible shifts and so you could easily get your answer in seconds with just a handful of lines of code.

If your cipher text is short, like your example, you may not have enough information to guess at which character could be an 'E', or the next most used letter in the English alphabet.

Comment: Too little text for frequency analysis anyway.

Comment: @Fellesh - even for the longer text, all you would need to do is take the first ten or so words and decrypt using all 26 possible shifts.  Once you figure the key for that sample, then apply it to the complete cipher text.  As for all symbols disappearing, don't apply any shift to characters that are not in the ASCII range of 65-90 (A-Z), as only the alphabetic characters have been encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Frequency analysis only works for input that is sufficiently large. The chance of a character being more abundant than the letter `E` becomes significant for small text. For instance, in question 1 the letter `Y` seems to be (one of) the most abundant characters in the plaintext, represented by the letter `J` in the ciphertext.

So for smaller text you simply rely on brute force and manual labor (if you consider reading 25 sentences labor). Just print out the 25 possible plaintexts as well as the shift, and then choose the one that resembles a sentence. It is of course possible to compare the words in the sentence with a dictionary, but I doubt that this is what was intended.